# Cant connect to custom TCP port when app hosted on uwsgi

Tags: python, rpc, uwsgi

APPLICATION : Python Bottle -> uWSGI -> nGINX

What I basically want to do is expose some of my Class Methods for direct access from any other machine (RPC). I have developed something very similar to [Zero RPC](http://zerorpc.dotcloud.com/). But the problem is that when I run my application through uWSGI, I cannot connect to my tcp port. I think uWSGI blocks direct TCP traffic.

It runs fine when I run it as Python app `$ python myapp.py`

I'm running uwsgi in emperor mode `uwsgi --emperor path/to/my/vassals/`

[EDIT]

Here's my uwsgi vassal

```
<uwsgi>

<master>true</master>

<processes>1</processes>

<vaccum>true</vaccum>

<plugins>python</plugins>

<chmod-socket>777</chmod-socket>

<socket>127.0.0.1:8484</socket>

<uid>www-data</uid>

<gid>www-data</gid>

<pythonpath>%d../MY_APP/</pythonpath>

<module>MyApp</module>

</uwsgi>
```

Clarifying my problem,

the MyApp opens an TCP Socket for exposing few of its methods. To which I'm not able to connect.

Comment: You'll need to post the vassal config / uwsgi.ini, there are so many ways to setup UWSGI that I can't tell what's wrong from your description. How are you telling uWSGI which port to listen on for instance?

Comment: is the address `127.0.0.1:8484` not accessible from localhost? You can not connect to it from any other computer. Sorry if you knew this. What do you do to connect?

Comment: No. My app opens a port (say 5000) for RPC to which I'm unable to connect.